# Best 192k interface

Tags: gear, sampling, hardware, interface, 192khz

What interface is everyone using for editing 192k audio files? I am using an mBox Pro at home but am limited to 96k, but want to start taking full advantage of the beauty if 192k recordings when I use my Sound Devices recorder.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I'm assuming you're on ProTools LE?
If so, you'll need to go HD with 192 i/o

Comment: PT9 does 192 if your soundcard (anything from RME Fireface to MOTU) allows it. I own a fireface UC and it records beautifully at 192k, but remember it also comes down to the microphones, see this post by Tim Nielsen about his microphone addiction. He specifically mentions the Sennheiser MKH800 with a freq. range up to 50 kHz. Very expensive though.. 

Comment: Oops forgot the link: http://designingsound.org/2011/08/tim-nielsen-special-on-microphone-addiction/

Answer (score 1):

Apogee, if you can afford it.  The Rosetta is an awesome interface.  Sounds amazing.  You'll need the firewire option to use it as a stand-alone AD-DA.  (Rosetta 200 w/ FW option - $2150, Rosetta 800 w/ FW option - $3050)

If you can't afford it, I'd go with one of the MOTU units.  They have several units under $1000 that do 192k that are decent sounding.  Even the Ultralite does, which is a $550 USB interface.

Comment: Filipe has a good point - if you want to do 192k in Pro Tools, you're going to need an HD system.  Now, you can still use the Rosetta with the HD system instead of the 192 IO, you just need the right card with it (the x-symphony card instead of the FW option).  If you get the Rosetta 200 instead of the 192 IO, you save yourself $2000 (although you lose 14 inputs - which I'm assuming you don't need).  You'll still need an HD system however, which will set you back $7k in and of itself

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to HEAR the difference or just use 192kHz for latitude in processing? My 7-year-old MOTU 828mkII plays 192khz files recorded on my SD702 in real time just fine, it just dithers them to 96khz, and in my home studio, my room won't let me hear the difference even if my aging ears could. If you're just looking to record at 192kHz for processing latitude, wouldn't most other ProTools-happy interfaces do the same?

If you're looking to actually hear every bit of 192kHz, it does seem like the Apogee is the best value. I've worked with one but don't own one.

Comment: "downsamples them to 96 kHz"

Comment: I'm just looking for the latitude in processing. I would not be able to hear the difference in my room as well, but for sound design purposes 192k would be great.

Comment: thx, endolith, "downsamples" indeed!

Comment: Unfortunately, Pro Tools LE is limited to 24/96.  I love digidesign.  

Answer (score 0):

The best interfaces I've ever used is Lynx Studio's second generation DAC/ADC! In the interfaces they have absolutely nothing other than GenLock, SMPTE (LynxTWO and Aurora), and as close to noise-less, jitter-less and faithful to the signal as it's possible to get as far as I know (LynxTWO, Aurora and L22).

On the other hand, if you want stuff like mic-amps, MIDI, effects and processing for example, there are none.

I only use LynxTWO-cards (and will add an Aurora soon) for regular recording in the studio myself. I do have some Yamaha DSP Factory cards, an Focusrite Saffire, and some different Sound Blaster cards too, but I only have them for effects and degrading :-)
/CvanC

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple of the Digidesign 192s which are rock solid.  To date (5 years) we have never had a single problem with them.  We have a Digidesign Mic Pre on the front end.